# Can we import the random forest model built using SparkR to R and then use getTree to extract one of the trees?

Tags: r, apache-spark, random-forest, sparkr

Like in decision tree we can see or visualize the node splits , I want to do something similar . But I am using SparkR and it does not have decision trees. So I am planning to use random forest with 1 tree as parameter and run on SparkR, then save the model and use getTree to see the node splits and further visualize using ggplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

Models built with SparkR are not compatible with ones built with the respective R packages, in this case `randomForest`; hence, you will not be able to use the `getTree` function from the latter to visualize a tree from a random forest built with SparkR.

On a different level: I am surprised that decision trees have still not found their way into SparkR - they seem to be ready since several months now in the [Github repo](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/r/ml); but even when they are, they are not expected to offer methods for visualizing trees, and you will still not be able to use functions from other R packages for that purpose.